# Water animation in final render completely different from preview

Tags: rendering

I have this water animation that in preview render works just fine but when I put it in final rendering all that it shows is just a watercube. It's not really important to fix this, It just bugs me a lot that I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm really new to blender so I don't even know were to look, help would be really appreciated!

Here's the file:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Final]

You had disabled **Use modifier during render** in **Modifier Tab** or in **Outliner**.